# Help identifying a piece - round, about the size of a 1x1 brick

Tags: part-identification

Brick has "C 16" on it.

[image: round piece about 1x1]

Answer (score 4):

BrickLink calls it a [33286](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=33286) Brick, Round 1 x 1 x 2/3 with Flower Edge (4 Knobs on Base)